# Setting Default Shell in VSCode on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code

When I open a new terminal (via iTerm.app)

```
| => echo $SHELL
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

When I open the Visual Studio Code app I get an error message right away:

```
Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occurred (spawn /usr/local/bin/bash ENOENT)
```

When I open a terminal in VSCode:

```
| => echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

In my `settings.json` file I have the following:

```
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "homebrew bash": { // profile name
            "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/bash",
            "args": []
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "homebrew bash",
```

I have a feeling VSCode is using the wrong shell when executing scripts from extensions. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Inspected `/usr/local/bin/bash` and it wasn't even there. Created a symbolic link, `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash`, and now everything works again.